# Shallow copy in Python dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, copy

I have the below piece of Python code in which i am trying to implement shallow copy operation in dictionary:

```
d = {'name':'Subhayan','age':32,'friends':['papa','mama']}
new_d = d.copy()
new_d['friends'] = []

print (d)
print (new_d)
```

Now as per my understanding if there is a nested data structure like a list in my case shallow copy would not work. And the changes in new_d dict would affect the d dict as well.

Can someone let me know if my understanding is correct?

The answer which i get after running this script is something different.

```
{'name': 'Subhayan', 'age': 32, 'friends': ['papa', 'mama']}
{'name': 'Subhayan', 'age': 32, 'friends': []}
```

Aparently this is doing a deepcopy .

Where i am going wrong ?

Comment: Yes, references are not "deep-copied" as part of your d.copy().
If you like to copy them too, you'll need to use copy.deepcopy(d).
Otherwise, if you want to have an "empty" references, you'll have to implement your own copy function....

Comment: Bear in mind the difference between performing an assignment, which binds a new object to a name, and performing a mutation on the existing object that's bound to a name. See what happens when you do this mutation `new_d['friends'][:] = []`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code as-written will not run into aliasing issues.  However, if you modify one of the values **in** the list, that change will appear in both dictionaries.

```
d = {'name':'Subhayan','age':32,'friends':['papa','mama']}
new_d = d.copy()
new_d['friends'][0] = 'new value'

print (d)
print (new_d)

# returns:
{'age': 32, 'name': 'Subhayan', 'friends': ['new value', 'mama']}
{'age': 32, 'name': 'Subhayan', 'friends': ['new value', 'mama']}
```

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html:
A shallow copy constructs a new compound object and then (to the extent possible) inserts references into it to the objects found in the original.

- The new compound object is new_d
- the objects found in the original are "mama" and "papa"
- so the references are references to "mama" and "papa"

You did not change the content of a referenced object, you changed the object (a list) itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you want objects within the dictionary to be changed when the new dictionary is changed, you shouldn't use `copy` or `deepcopy` at all;

Just assign new_d to d:

```
d = {'name':'Subhayan','age':32,'friends':['papa','mama']}
new_d = d
new_d['friends'] = []

assert d['friends'] == []
```